# How to remove a Label in UserForm?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm with this function:

```
Public MyVariable As String
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 [...my code...]
End Sub
```

To call my Userform from a button i do:

```
Sub CallUserForm_Appro()
    UserForm1.MyVariable = "Appro"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub CallUserForm_User()
    UserForm1.MyVariable = "User"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

My goal is to remove "Label1" if user click on button to call `CallUserForm_Appro()`

So, i tried in `UserForm_Initialize()` to do:

```
Public MyVariable As String
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 [...my code...]
 If MyVariable = "Appro" Then
  UserForm1.Controls.Remove "Label1"
 End If

End Sub
```

I have no error but my Label1 is always visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you set the visibility of the label to false:

```
UserForm1.label1.Visible = false
```

Then it should not be visible any more.

Comment: Thx, it's works. So, i added your code in CallUserForm_Appro() function

Answer (score 1):

The `Initialize event occurs before the variable is set (because you can't access any property of the form without it being loaded first).

You should use the `Activate` event instead as long as the control is added at run time. If it's a design time control, you can't delete it, only hide it. Alternatively, you might only add it to the form if the variable is *not* set to "Appro"

Comment: Thx for your explanation